# Android Studio compile error: cannot access classB class file for classB not found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

The source code is:

```
ClassC c = new ClassC();
ClassA a = new ClassA(c);
```

where ClassA and ClassC are referenced from testA.jar. ClassA has two constructor:

```
import testA.ClassC;
import testB.ClassB;

public class ClassA {
    // constructor with b
    ClassA(ClassB b) {
    }

    // constructor with c
    ClassA(ClassC c) {
    }
}
```

which ClassB is referenced from another jar testB.jar and testB.jar is not added to project.

when build my source code on Eclipse, everything is ok. But when build on android studio with gradle, the following errors occur:

```
error: cannot access ClassB
      ClassA a = new ClassA(c);
                 ^
class file for testB.ClassB not found
1 error
```

As I know, classB should not be checked at build time. Can anyone help me for this problem?

Comment: ClassB is from a jar file? Did you let Gradle compile that jar file?

Comment: Did you include testB.jar in your build dependencies? It is apparent that ClassA needs testB.jar.

Comment: probably just a typo : `import testB.classB;` should be `import testB.ClassB;` ?

Comment: @cricket_007 testB.jar is not added to the project. There is no build problem on Eclipse. But error occurs on Android studio.

Comment: @Mussa The ClassB is not referenced in my source code. so testB.jar is not added to the project.

Comment: @MarkKeen classB is my spell error when writing this question

Comment: @ixp its not about your source code. It is referenced in ClassA.

Comment: @Mussa yes. but the referenced class should be loaded by JVM at runtime, should not at build time.